# how to display an array in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a function that gets me data as follows

```
function Model(){
self.DataArray=[];
    self.GetDepartmentData = function () {
        var params = { shiftsBackward: self.ShiftsBackwardToDisplay, shiftsForward: 1, departmentId:department};
        console.log(params);
         Ajax.Get({
             url: DATA,

            params: params,
            success: function (data) {
                self.DataArray = data[0];

            }

        });
    }
    }
```

which gets me the output i require as following

```
Object {data: Array[1]}
data: Array[1]
0: Object
department: "1"
ShiftName: "Day"
Total: 61
```

how ever when im trying to bind it to the default.aspx page its not showing me anything.i did link the controller to the page

```
<div ng-controller="controllerData">

       <div ng-model="model.DataArray">

           {{model.department}} 
            {{model.total}}

       </div>
```

Comment: Instead of model.DataArray can you try controllerData.DataArray. And for displaying try controllerData.DataArray.department

Comment: tried that now,it still doesnt display anything.its not even given an error so i cant figure out whats going wrong

Comment: Can your try  `self.DataArray = data;` and for displaying try ng-repeat just for a testing purpose. `<div ng-repeat="obj in controllerData.DataArray "> obj.department </div>`. Do declare var obj;

Comment: if you can create a jsFiddle for this, I will fix it for sure

Comment: try directly like department and total else, as Imcoder pointed out, use ng-repeat for test purpose

Comment: i added the ng-repeat and nothing happend then i changed my function from DataArray=data to DataArray=data.data and it worked

Answer (score 4):

In Order to get Array you should use ng-repeat

```
   <div ng-repeat="dataarr in DataArray">

      <span> {{dataarr.department}} </span>
      <span> {{dataarr.total}} </span>


   </div>
```

Comment: Did you try this answer?